# NO CSS displayed in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am in the process of coding the site,

it's pretty much done, but **FIREFOX DOESN'T LOAD THE CSS!** It works perfect on Chrome, and on IE! Could you tell me where I have gone wrong?

(Using WordPress 3.4.1, Toolbox framework)

I'm guessing it might be due to the fact that WP loads CSS dynamically.

**Edit:**

the site link is below:

http://www.code-warriors.org/

Comment: show to website link ..........

Comment: Show your code or we can't help

Comment: Eh? I'm pretty sure I put it somewhere.. anyways, [link]http://code-warriors.org[/link] code - warriors dot org

Comment: @Namanyayg.. please put your quesion update in Question block so community can see your updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey now check to your css path 
and put as like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="xxxxxxxxxxx.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```